# error when adding lm to datetime data in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

When Trying to plot the linear regression of the data the output returns a horizontal line with a warning that the fit is rank-deficient. Can someone please explain how to display a proper linear regression?

Sample Data

```
ToPlot <- structure(list(Time = structure(c(1643126476.049, 1643126476.099, 
1643126476.149, 1643126476.199, 1643126476.249, 1643126476.299, 
1643126476.349, 1643126476.399, 1643126476.449, 1643126476.499, 
1643126476.549, 1643126476.599, 1643126476.649, 1643126476.699, 
1643126476.749, 1643126476.799, 1643126476.849, 1643126476.899, 
1643126476.949, 1643126476.999), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), LIN = c(112.05611159876, 112.66549348, 113.37316276144, 
113.86459976244, 114.59192652392, 115.29959580536, 115.88932020656, 
116.61664696804, 117.20637136924, 117.93369813072, 118.52342253192, 
119.13280441316, 119.8404736946, 120.54814297604, 121.15752485728, 
121.86519413872, 122.47457601996, 123.1822453014, 123.79162718264, 
124.49929646408)), row.names = 314:333, class = "data.frame")
```

Code:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")

ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = LIN), data = ToPlot) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%H:%m:%S"))+
  geom_smooth(method='lm')
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [predict.lm() in a loop. warning: prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26558631/8366499)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the package picks the orientation (x or y) automatically. However, when it becomes uncertain, you see that message. You don't need to specify the formula, you can just specify the orientation.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")

ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = LIN), data = ToPlot) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%H:%m:%S"))+
  geom_smooth(method='lm', orientation = "y")
```

[image]

Comment: This is because you are performing the regression `Time ~ LIN` rather than `LIN ~ Time`. `lm` manages the first but not the second.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a `ggplot` problem, but an `lm` problem:

```r
lm(LIN ~ Time, data = ToPlot)
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = LIN ~ Time, data = ToPlot)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)         Time  
#>      118.2           NA
```

I think the issue here isn't the `POSIXct` format, but just that it seems to choke on the large numbers for some reason (you get the same result if you convert `Time` to numeric).

One way to get round this is simply to subtract the large constant number of seconds in the POSIXct within the `formula` argument:

```r
ToPlot <- structure(list(Time = structure(c(1643126476.049, 1643126476.099, 
1643126476.149, 1643126476.199, 1643126476.249, 1643126476.299, 
1643126476.349, 1643126476.399, 1643126476.449, 1643126476.499, 
1643126476.549, 1643126476.599, 1643126476.649, 1643126476.699, 
1643126476.749, 1643126476.799, 1643126476.849, 1643126476.899, 
1643126476.949, 1643126476.999), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), LIN = c(112.05611159876, 112.66549348, 113.37316276144, 
113.86459976244, 114.59192652392, 115.29959580536, 115.88932020656, 
116.61664696804, 117.20637136924, 117.93369813072, 118.52342253192, 
119.13280441316, 119.8404736946, 120.54814297604, 121.15752485728, 
121.86519413872, 122.47457601996, 123.1822453014, 123.79162718264, 
124.49929646408)), row.names = 314:333, class = "data.frame")

library("ggplot2")
library("scales")

datemin <- floor(as.numeric(min(ToPlot$Time)))

ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = LIN), data = ToPlot) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%H:%m:%S"))+
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ I(x - datemin), method='lm')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, If you could automate fetching of the max value I would consider it solved.

Comment: I get the error `object 'y' not found `

Comment: Strange. The code above is a full reprex, including automating  the minimum value as requested.